# Is there shorthand assign value to map in dart?

Tags: dart

```
var save({height, name}) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = {};
      var setData = (map, key, data) {
        if (data != null) {
          map[key] = data;
        }
      };
      setData(data, 'height', height);
      setData(data, 'name', name);
      return data;
}
```

I want to make function that not acceptable null value on map.

```
save(height: 123); // want { height: 123 } NOT { height: 123, name: null }
```

I think that code is silly or too much.

I usally write javascript.
Is that right code for dart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
void main() {
  Map<String, int> map = {};
  map.addAllNonNullKeys({"Age": 5, "Houses": 2, "test": null});
  print(map); // {Age: 5, Houses: 2}
}

extension AddAllNonNullKeysExtension<K, V> on Map<K, V> {
  void addAllNonNullKeys(Map<K, V> map) =>
      this.addEntries(map.entries.where((entry) => entry.value != null));
}
```